# How to show a device in bus and class?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device, bus

How show the same struct device in bus and class in sysfs structure? I'm getting an error when doing this. Currently I'm assigning bus and class attributes of struct device before calling device_register. The error message says that a device in /device of the same name already exists.

Comment: struct bus_type and struct device type are two different things.  A device has a class but a bus does not.  mei, for example, creates both a bus and a device.

Comment: a device has a bus attribute to link a device with the bus, also it haves a class attribute to link with a class. however, when I tried to link both before calling device_register I got an error.